# iOS: tap gesture mistakenly recognized during quick pan gesture. Use requireGestureRecognizerToFail or create custom tap gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

The goal is to allow both pan and tap gestures in an iOS app (along with other gestures). However, very quick pans sometimes get mistakenly interpreted as taps as well as pans.

The class docs for `UITapGestureRecognizer` only show two properties for configuration: `numberOfTapsRequired` and `numberOfTouchesRequired.` Neither help prevent the undesired behavior.

Defining the maximum distance a touch can move before invalidating a tap would be ideal, i.e., if the user moves his finger > 10 pixels, don't treat the gesture as a tap.

The current approach, which seems to work against light testing, is to use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` against the other gestures which should not get confused for tap gestures. However, some users suggested implementing a custom tap gesture recognizer.

Is `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` the right way, or is it required to roll a custom version of UITapGestureRecognizer to eliminate the unwanted behavior?

```
private func setSceneViewGestureRecognizers() {
    // Handle one-finger pans
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedOneFinger))
    panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panRecognizer.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

    // Handle two-finger pans
    let twoFingerPanRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedTwoFingers))
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerPanRecognizer)

    // Handle pinches
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPinched))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

    // Handle taps
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewTapped))
    tapRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(panRecognizer)
    tapRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(twoFingerPanRecognizer)
    tapRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(pinchGesture)
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: From your code it looks as though you are handling the desired actions associated with your gesture recognizer via delegate methods. Have you thought instead about creating specific targets for each gesture recognizer? If you did it this way you could add a guard statement to the top of the target method to check that recognizer.state == .Ended. This will probably eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: @Sparky Interesting. Could you post as an answer and elaborate? You might create a special class just to handle the pan, for instance? If you create a special class, why would you even need a guard statement since that class should only be receiving one event (i.e., the pan event)?